# How to set field "Summariser Date Format" in Jenkins Performance Plugin

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I have summary results generated every 30 seconds in jmeter.log during performance test, like the ones below. I would like to use Jenkins plugin "Publish Performance test result report" to parse the jmeter.log after the test, but there is this field "Summariser Date Format" in the plugin that needs to fill in. What exactly should I put in this field? I tried "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" but didn't work.

2018-09-07 04:26:30,000 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: HTTP Request2 Summary Results = 170712 in 00:01:44 = 1637.5/s Avg:     4 Min:     1 Max:  1046 Err:     0 (0.00%)

2018-09-07 04:26:30,000 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: HTTP Request1 Summary Results = 222478 in 00:01:44 = 2134.1/s Avg:     5 Min:     2 Max:   194 Err:     0 (0.00%)

2018-09-07 04:27:00,000 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: HTTP Request2 Summary Results +  77536 in 00:00:30 = 2584.5/s Avg:     5 Min:     1 Max:  1034 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 33 Started: 33 Finished: 0

2018-09-07 04:27:00,000 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: HTTP Request1 Summary Results +  93465 in 00:00:30 = 3115.5/s Avg:     6 Min:     3 Max:   142 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 33 Started: 33 Finished: 0

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the configuration screen ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of only [this Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) and it doesn't have anything like `Summariser Date Format`

[image: JMeter Performance Plugin Configuration]

So make sure to [update the performance plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#updating-a-plugin) to the latest version (`3.11` as of now) and try this out.

[image: JMeter Performance Plugin Version]

More information: [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)